# Locate a word in an output list of a program

Tags: unix, grep, echo

I am using gromacs to do simulations. Using the tool g_polystat results in the following procedure.

```
g_polystat
```

the program returns a list of choices:

```
Select a group of polymer mainchain atoms:
Group     0 (         System) has  2669 elements
Group     1 (          Other) has    23 elements
Group     2 (           LnrB) has     5 elements
Group     3 (            Lnr) has    14 elements
Group     4 (           LnrE) has     4 elements
Group     5 (          Water) has  2646 elements
Group     6 (            SOL) has  2646 elements
Group     7 (      non-Water) has    23 elements
Select a group:
```

the program asks to choose the group you want and confirm it with ENTER.

If one wants group 2 the procedure automates:

```
echo 2 | g_polystat
```

Is it possible to use some unix command and search the above output list for a word and then choose the group you want.

eg

1. find the word you want lets say Water. Something like grep will do the job
2. Locate the number of the group that this belongs. In this case its Group 5
3. then write

   echo 5 | g_polystat

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps `expect` can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Answer (score 0):

Ummm...

Won't this just do it?

```
#### answer.sh
#!/bin/sh

sed -rn "s/Group[ ]*([0-9]*)[ ]*\([ ]*$1\)[ ]*has[ ]*[0-9]* elements/\1/gp" < /dev/stdin
```

Then run like so

```
./answer.sh Water < tableFile
```

Prints

```
5
```

So you can just edit the code like this:

```
sed -rn "s/Group[ ]*([0-9]*)[ ]*\([ ]*$1\)[ ]*has[ ]*[0-9]* elements/\1/gp" < /dev/stdin | {
    read num;
    echo $num;
    echo $num | g_polystat;
}
```

You'll obviously need some null-checking in the piped application, but seems sufficient to me